# Openlayers Views map with auto render?

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I have an openlayers map view that is populated with user IP address.
I need the map to update automatically (without refreshing) when a new users visits the site.

Much like the behavior of the map on http://drupal.org/ i.e markers would appear but stay on map.

If anyone can point me into the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, here is a description on how the map on the D.O homepage was built. https://association.drupal.org/node/784

To achieve what you want, you could use the [Views Auto-refresh](http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks#views_autorefresh) submodule of the [Views Hacks](http://drupal.org/project/views_hack) module to auto refresh the openlayers map view in short intervals.